# issue with deploying django application with gunicorn, supervisorctl

Tags: django, nginx, gunicorn, supervisord

I'm deploying django application using gunicorn, supervisorctl and nginx but I'm getting the below error in nginx log file

```
172.69.178.94 - - [12/Oct/2023:11:18:52 +0000] "POST /api/notify/send-notification HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
2023/10/12 11:24:05 [crit] 551667#551667: *1 connect() to unix:/home/pankaj/cn_notification/cn_notification/cn_notify.sock failed (13: Permission denied) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.69.178.95, server: notify.codingnap.com, request: "POST /api/notify/send-notification HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://unix:/home/pankaj/cn_notification/cn_notification/cn_notify.sock:/api/notify/send-notification", host: "notify.codingnap.com"
172.69.178.95 - - [12/Oct/2023:11:24:05 +0000] "POST /api/notify/send-notification HTTP/1.1" 502 166 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
```

My supervisor config file

```
[program:cn_notify]
directory=/home/pankaj/cn_notification/cn_notification
command=/home/pankaj/cn_notification/notify-venv/bin/gunicorn --workers 1 --bind unix:/home/pankaj/cn_notification/cn_notification/cn_notify.sock cn_notify.wsgi:application
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/cn_notify.log
stdout_logfile=/var/log/cn_notify.log
user=pankaj
group=www-data

[group:guni]
programs:cn_notify
```

and nginx config file

```
server {
listen 80;
server_name notify.codingnap.com;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/cn_notify_log;
access_log /var/log/nginx/cn_notify_log;

location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
location /static/ {
    root /home/pankaj/cn_notification/cn_notification;
}

location / {
    include proxy_params;
    proxy_pass http://unix:/home/pankaj/cn_notification/cn_notification/cn_notify.sock;
}
}
```

What could be the possible way to solve this issue